# excel Max: how can I choose to ignore non-number entries?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel

I have a column (L) of numbers calculated from a neighbouring column (K).
Each of the numbers is calculated like L11 =value(K11), but some of the entries in K are invalid resulting in L11 #VALUE!

=MAX(L3:L2000) then produces #VALUE! But MAX should ignore text entries.
How do I get Excel to ignore this text?

Answer (score 0):

Use `IFERROR` function to check for error. Try the following formula:

```
=MAX(IFERROR(L3:L2000,0))
```

In this case, the `IFERROR` function returns `0` is an error (`#VALUE`) is found.

Comment: Thank you - but.  This throws an error if there is an error anywhere in L3:L2000. I want that error to be ignored, and the max function to work on all the non-error values.

Comment: @cvhManchester What error does it throws? It might be that you use different regional settings than mine. Try: `=MAX(IFERROR(L3:L2000;0))`

Comment: I am sorry, I mis-spoke. The error was in the answer, "0", not in Excel.  My spreadsheet is a database which contains mixed data - some of which throw up Excel errors #VALUE!  I am happy to ignore this data and errors, and I want Excel to ignore them in implementing the MAX function.  I have tried using an IF function to catch the errors L480 =IF(VALUE(K480)=TRUE,VALUE(K480),0) K480 being T481. I also tried L480=IF(VALUE(K480)=#VALUE!,0,VALUE(K480)).   But L480 still ends up as #VALUE!  Any ideas?  Although Excel shows #VALUE! on the spreadsheet screen, that seems not what Excel uses.